# How to get rid of a long vertical gap coming above and below an equation coming at some places!

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, enumerate, itemize, white-space

I am preparing part of a big latex report. At some places, I see unnecessary additional vertical space around equations. When I try it individually with short text, it works fine. Somehow, I suspect it is because of enumerations/itemized lists but I am not sure of the same. Since it is a big report, I cannot paste it here. Can somebody provide some pointers on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Wrapping `equation` in a `center` environment is wrong. Remove it.

Comment: you get spurious vertical space from the `center` also remove the `tabular` which is not intended for equation sat all, the `aligned` environment will align the = without need of a nested alignment.

Comment: In addition, extra vertical space can be caused by having a large unbreakable thing on the next page, so that TeX spaces things out to avoid a large blank area at the bottom of the current page.

Comment: Problem solved?